# updating a sql table with a datagridview using template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagridview, templatefield

so the thing is i want to limit what can the user insert when updating through a datagridview. i thought of converting that specific field into a template and make it a dropdownlist with limited options to update such field. the thing is that when i run tests with this it updates the field as null. the sqldatasource bound to the datagridview updates perfectly fine without the template field.

i was able to make this work on a table without much problem but when i tried the same thing for another table it kept giving me a null value on the dropdownlist. this latter is bound to a SqlDataSource. i checked the code on the gridview and the data source and its pretty much the same. i don't see whats the problem.

This is the code of my SqlDataSource

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlCoord" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sistema_gestion_calidadConnectionString %>" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        SelectCommand="SELECT profesor.nombre + ' ' + profesor.apellidos AS Expr1, materia.nombre_materia, coordinadores.id_coordinador, coordinadores.id_materia, coordinadores.id_profesor FROM coordinadores INNER JOIN materia ON coordinadores.id_materia = materia.id_materia INNER JOIN profesor ON coordinadores.id_profesor = profesor.id_profesor"             
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE coordinadores SET id_materia = @id_materia, id_profesor = @id_profesor FROM coordinadores INNER JOIN profesor ON coordinadores.id_profesor = profesor.id_profesor INNER JOIN materia ON coordinadores.id_materia = materia.id_materia WHERE (coordinadores.id_coordinador = @original_id_coordinador)">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id_materia" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id_profesor" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_id_coordinador" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is my DataGridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_coordinador" 
        DataSourceID="SqlCoord" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profesor" SortExpression="Profesor">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlProfs" 
                        DataTextField="Expr1" DataValueField="id_profesor">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlProfs" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sistema_gestion_calidadConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT id_profesor, nombre + ' ' + apellidos AS Expr1 FROM profesor">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Expr1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="nombre_materia" SortExpression="nombre_materia">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlMats" 
                        DataTextField="nombre_materia" DataValueField="id_materia">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlMats" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sistema_gestion_calidadConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [id_materia], [nombre_materia] FROM [materia]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nombre_materia") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_coordinador" HeaderText="id_coordinador" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="id_coordinador" InsertVisible="False" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_materia" HeaderText="id_materia" 
                SortExpression="id_materia" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_profesor" HeaderText="id_profesor" 
                SortExpression="id_profesor" Visible="False" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: We need to see your code to figure out what's not working. Sounds like it could be the order of the databinding you're doing. What you describe that you want is possible (if I'm reading you right).

Comment: thanks for the early reply and interest to help but i already figured out the problem. i was binding to another datasource that i forgot to delete when i was testing.... derp moments sorry